# How to use powershell to split a file into individual record files

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell, enjoying learning the basics, but I'm a bit lost with where to start on this one.

- I need to be able to split an incoming file in to individual records.
- Each line of the file contains variable quantities of alphanumeric strings.
- Each record contains a variable number of sequential lines of the file.
- The file contains a variable number of records.
- The start of each record can be identified by a specific alphanumeric string.
- The end of each record can be identified by a specific alphanumeric string.
- Start and end lines also contain record data so need to be included in each record / output file.

---

**Example Input file**

**File name data.txt**

### Content:

```
RECSTART001 RECkjdsfgjk4897 0934578ldkfjgk recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC765 shop9994 product345 lkdhfgjh74654001 START897
REC84 SEPTEMBER9 kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  dog
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
RECSTART001 FREDkjdsfgjk4897 line 2 recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC765 shop9991 product666 lkdhfgjh74654001 END897
REC84 SEPTEMBER kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  cat APRIL 1 2  888 9
REC84 SEPTEMBER kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  fish APRIL food sd d g8 r2
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
RECSTART001 RECkjdsfgjk4897 0934578ldkfjgk recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC001 shop9994 product345 lkdhfgjh74654001 START897
REC12 Vanilla9 dip456097 mint 84 RECfgh 234 67   555  box
REC765 break lolly097 bmw 84 RECfgh 234 bingo   555  cabbage 984756 djd 8
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
```

---

**Desired Output files**

**File name data.rec001.txt**

### Content:

```
RECSTART001 RECkjdsfgjk4897 0934578ldkfjgk recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC765 shop9994 product345 lkdhfgjh74654001 START897
REC84 SEPTEMBER9 kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  dog
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
```

---

**File name data.rec002.txt**

### Content:

```
RECSTART001 FREDkjdsfgjk4897 line 2 recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC765 shop9991 product666 lkdhfgjh74654001 END897
REC84 SEPTEMBER kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  cat APRIL 1 2  888 9
REC84 SEPTEMBER kjh456097 765 84 RECfgh 234 67   123  fish APRIL food sd d g8 r2
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
```

---

**File name data.rec003.txt**

### Content:

```
RECSTART001 RECkjdsfgjk4897 0934578ldkfjgk recfgh lkjsef 3459086001
REC001 shop9994 product345 lkdhfgjh74654001 START897
REC12 Vanilla9 dip456097 mint 84 RECfgh 234 67   555  box
REC765 break lolly097 bmw 84 RECfgh 234 bingo   555  cabbage 984756 djd 8
RECEND shop9994 0934578ldkfjgk 234 67   123  dog
```

---

Is this possible with powershell? if so, where do I start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using get-content and split. get-contet will read the doc and you can then split the info at RECSTART001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to change to a new file after every time a line began with `RECEND`:

```
param (
    $FilePath = 'C:\Temp\data.txt',
    $OutputFolder = 'C:\Temp'
)

$Counter = 1
Get-Content $FilePath | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $FileName = "$OutputFolder\data.rec{0:D3}.txt" -f $Counter
    $_ | Add-Content -Path $FileName
    if ( $_ -like "RECEND*" )
    {
        $Counter ++
    }
}
```

If you wanted to start a new file every time a line started with `RECSTART`:

```
param (
    $FilePath = 'C:\Temp\data.txt',
    $OutputFolder = 'C:\Temp'
)

$Counter = 0
Get-Content $FilePath | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ( $_ -like "RECSTART*" )
    {
        $Counter ++
    }
    $FileName = "$OutputFolder\data.rec{0:D3}.txt" -f $Counter
    $_ | Add-Content -Path $FileName
}
```

Comment: I would check with the OP to see if the records will always start at 1 in the record. I suspect that they won't. Better to get the record number from the string IMO.

Comment: @EBGreen Per his example data, all of the records start the same way.

Comment: Unbelievable, it took me far longer to write the question than it did for you to write the code! Many, many thanks, you are a star @Shawn-Esterman

Comment: So I see. Good catch.

Comment: @overflow_paul I wish all the solutions I wrote were as elegant as this, but your requirements were easy to solve with a loop and counter.

Comment: Hi  @Shawn-Esterman , if I was no longer able to reliably identify the end of file in the above example, could the above code be altered to use the starting RECSTART001 to create the required part files? I've tried adjust the code for the correct search string, but it just sends all the content from the source file to data.rec001.txt - obviously don't quite understand the logic just yet....  Any help would be much appreciated - cheers, Paul

Comment: @overflow_paul Sure. I added an example that would increment the counter every time a line started with `RECSTART`.

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks again @Shawn-Esterman. Hope you have a great Christmas! :)